# requirejs - how to load modules on condition - what solution is good

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have problem with requirejs, and importing modules on conditions. For example I have login page, with some modules. Some off them use only when user is logged, another when user is not logged. Of course I don't want users ability to register, when they logged in. So I have two difrent solutions:

First solution: require only things I needed:

```
define(['jquery', 'dst!/static/dust/frontend/user_menu.dust'], function($, template) {
    var handleResponse = function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'not_logged') {
            require(["user/frontend/register"]);
            require(["user/frontend/login"], function(l) {

            });
        } else {
            require(["user/frontend/logout"]);
            require(["user/frontend/change_password"]);
            require(["user/frontend/profile_details"]);
        }
        template(data, function(err, html) {
            $('#userMenu').html(html);
        });

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/user/info/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: handleResponse
    });     
});
```

That give me extra easy to read code, but I can't optimizes it with r.js tool.

Second solution:

```
define(['jquery', 'dst!/static/dust/frontend/user_menu.dust',
'user/frontend/register', 'user/frontend/login', 'user/frontend/logout', 
'user/frontend/change_password',
'user/frontend/profile_details'], function($, template, register, login, change_password, profile_details) {
    var handleResponse = function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'not_logged') {
            register.init();
            login.init();

        } else {
            logout.init();
            profile_details.init(); 
            change_password.init();

        }

        template(data, function(err, html) {
            $('#userMenu').html(html);
        });

    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/user/info/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: handleResponse
    });
});
```

It's hard to read. Everything is loaded to memory.

Maybe there are some another options to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a little library I created: [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy)

It allows you to lazy-load modules with an easy syntax:

```
define(["lazy!moduleWhenLogged", "lazy!moduleWhenAnonymous",
function(moduleWhenLogged, moduleWhenAnonymous) {
    ...
    if( logginSucceeded ) {
        moduleWhenLogged.get().then(function(realModule) {
            ...
        });
    ...
});
```

Lazy loaded text too!

```
define(["lazy!text!foo.html", ...
```

And works with r.js (i.e. bundles different modules into separate JS files, according to the dependency graph).

Not a lot of documentation yet, but I have lots of examples. There are also Grunt, Bower plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I find one solution, but it's broke my project in some way. I can create different init files for each view (when user is logged, and when he isn't). Optimizer will work right (file will be smaller).

**init-logged.js**

```
require([
//jquery plugins etc.
'jquery', 'libs/jquery.cookie', 'libs/csrf',
//main modules
'user/frontend/register', 'user/frontend/login', 
]);
```

**init-singup.js**

```
require([
//jquery plugins etc.
'jquery', 'libs/jquery.cookie', 'libs/csrf',
//main modules
'user/frontend/logout', 'user/frontend/change_password',  'user/frontend/profile_details',
]);
```

And after that, just optimize with r.js. Chose file same as in example 1. And include.